# Bibliography is not printing, I'm getting the error message "Empty bibliography"

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, overleaf

I'm writing in Overleaf and my bibliography is not printing. I have a references.bib file that I though I was importing with \addbibresource{references.bib} and then printing with \printbibliography but there is nothing at all printing. Instead I'm getting tons of errors;

- BibTeX: Cannot find 'MyCollection.bib'!
- Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file: output and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
- Empty bibliography on input line 46.
- There were undefined references.

My reference file is

```
@article{Heede2014,
    author = {Heede, Richard},
    doi = {10.1007/s10584-013-0986-y},
    issn = {1573-1480},
    journal = {Climatic Change},
    number = {1},
    pages = {229--241},
    title = {Tracing anthropogenic carbon dioxide and methane emissions to fossil fuel and cement producers, 1854–2010},
    url = {https://doi.org/10.1007/s10584-013-0986-y},
    volume = {122},
    year = {2014}
}
@article{Mervelskemper2017,
    annote = {https://doi.org/10.1002/bse.1935},
    author = {Mervelskemper, Laura and Streit, Daniel},
    doi = {https://doi.org/10.1002/bse.1935},
    issn = {0964-4733},
    journal = {Business Strategy and the Environment},
    month = {may},
    number = {4},
    pages = {536--549},
    publisher = {John Wiley & Sons, Ltd},
    title = {Enhancing Market Valuation of ESG Performance: Is Integrated Reporting Keeping its Promise?},
    url = {https://doi.org/10.1002/bse.1935},
    volume = {26},
    year = {2017}
}
```

The document has a very short beginning;

```
\documentclass[12pt, openany]{book}
\input{setup/settings.tex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage{csquotes}
```

Also the MyCollection.bib is just so strange that its still in my error messages as I deleted the file and any code with it a long time ago. Thank you for taking your time to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out all I had to do was go to "logs" and use "Clear cached files". Now its up and running :) Apparently that's something you can try if your references are not working. From what I understand it's an Overleaf specific problem

Comment: That is (presumably) an overleaf-specific answer, so I have tagged the question overleaf (even though overleaf not mentioned anywhere)

Comment: Thanks David. It basically translated to "corrupt aux files" :)

Comment: Thank you David! Sorry, I'm still really new with all this.